# Converting radians to degrees

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, math, swift

I've got the following code that transforms a imageView and rotates it in its superview on touch:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {                              
    var touch: AnyObject? = event.allTouches()?.anyObject()
    var location = touch!.locationInView(touch!.view)

    var dx: Float = Float(location.x - hsbWheel250ImageView.center.x)
    var dy: Float = Float(location.y - hsbWheel250ImageView.center.y)
    var radians = atan2f(dy, dx)

    //deltaAngle is set in touchesBegan
    var angleDiff = deltaAngle - radians
    hsbWheel250ImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-angleDiffCGFloat, 0, 0, 1)

   //This is where my problem is

   var angleDiffCGFloat = CGFloat(deltaAngle - radians)
   var angleInDegrees = angleDiffCGFloat * (180.0 / Float(M_PI))
   println(angleInDegrees)

   //For the first 180 degrees of the rotation angleInDegrees returns the correct 
   //number i.e. 0-180. But then after 180, where it should return 181, 
   //it returns -179. Where it should return 270 it returns -90 and so on 
   //and so forth..
```

I've been trying to google my way around, but the only solution people are giving (when converting from radians to degrees) is the one above... I think this is simply a maths problem, but I'm afraid my brain has switched off for this one.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. Since you've answered your question, include the answer as an actual answer, not an edit to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`atan2f` returns the principal angle, which has a range from -π to +π (-180 to +180 degrees). You can either deal with the negative values explicitly or use `fmodf` to force the angles into the required range, e.g. change:

```
var angleInDegrees = angleDiffCGFloat * (180.0 / Float(M_PI))
```

to:

```
var angleInDegrees = fmodf(360.0 + angleDiffCGFloat * (180.0 / Float(M_PI)), 360.0);
```

Comment: This gives me the following values:

What should be 0 is -0;
what should be 90 is -90;
180 = -180;
270 = -270;

And then it goes to + 89 (what should have been + 271) ?

Comment: The following works: `var angleInDegrees = fmodf(360.0 + -angleDiff * (180.0 / Float(M_PI)), 360.0)` I needed to add 360 to negative angleDiffCGFloat... Otherwise it would give me the degrees in reverse order. Thanks for your help @Paul R

Comment: OK - great - glad we got there in the end!

Comment: `M_PI` is deprecated, use `Float.pi` instead.